# Class pointer to different .h file

Tags: c++, class

Helo stack people, I need your help in work I make. So I have to .h files first one is Course and the second is Student and I try to create function call getCourses but Unfortunately It's not going so well.My realization "Course ** courses" do not pass compiling and I do not know why not. I would appraise if you can help me to Understand my mistake and help me to fix them thanks.

getCourse - return list of courses

my Course .h file

```
#ifndef _CORSE_H
#define _CORSE_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"

class Course
{
public:
void init(std::string getName, int test1, int test2, int exam);
std::string getName();
int* getGrades();
double getFinalGrade();

private:
std::string _name;
int _exam;
int _test1;
int _test2;
};

#endif
```

My Student .h file-

```
#ifndef _STUDENT_H
#define _STUDENT_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Course.h"

class Student
{
public:
void init(std::string name, Course** courses, int crsCount);
std::string getName();
void setName(std::string name);
double getAvg();
int getCrsCount();
Course** getCourses();

private:
std::string _name;
Course** courses;
int _crsCount;
};


#endif
```

My get course function -

```
Course** student::getCourses()
{
  return(this->courses);
}
```

The problem in the "Course** getCourses();"initialization and this applies also to the init function and Course** getCourses(); function.
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note:C++ doe not support default-int

Comment: Why not use proper C++ collections, e.g. `std::vector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a circular dependency - each header tries to include the other, and you end up with one class defined before the other. This gives errors, because you have to declare a type before you can use its name.

`Course` doesn't depend on `Student` at all, so just remove the `#include` from that file.

The definition of `Student` only uses pointers to `Course` so it doesn't need the full definition. It only needs to know that the class exists, so you can replace the `#include` with a declaration:

```
class Course;
```

A couple more points:

- both headers should include `<string>` since they use `std::string`; but not `<iostream>` since they don't use any I/O streams;
- names beginning with an underscore and a capital, like `_CORSE_H`, are reserved. You should remove the underscores.
- you've mis-capitalised `Student` in the final code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Mike Seymour wrote your course function uses lowercase student in
    `Course** student::getCourses()`

Whereas you declared the class with a capital S.  Case does matter.